# Remove WooCommerce product tabs for specific products with Avada

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, tabs, product

Using WooCommerce 3.6.5 within the Avada theme.

We have one product with variations. The products with variation use WooCommerce Tabs in the presentation to give more information about the product. I need to retain this.
[I do not see WooCommerce Tabs as an option within my Wordpress/WooCommerce admin panel that I see on so many videos detailing how to change or use Tabs, or any plugin that looks like they manage this, so I am at a loss to how the tabs are being handled.]

I have a new simple product added to the site, but the simple product also gets the tabs prepopulated with information that is not relevant to the simple product, from the product with variations.

I have identified the Tabs as belonging to WooCommerce through using Firebug to reveal information on the Divs within the webpage.

I need to prevent the tabs being displayed on the one simple product and/or change the tabs presentation order, or number. Would be happy to limit this within PHP code.

Have found this page with what looks like useful information to limit the presentation of tabs -
https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/editing-product-data-tabs/

Section of code -

```
/**
 * Remove product data tabs
 */
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'woo_remove_product_tabs', 98 );

function woo_remove_product_tabs( $tabs ) {

    unset( $tabs['description'] );          // Remove the description tab
    unset( $tabs['reviews'] );          // Remove the reviews tab
    unset( $tabs['additional_information'] );   // Remove the additional information tab

    return $tabs;
}
```

What bothers me is the implementation of this code.

What is the "98" element after 'woo_remove_product_tabs', ? and how can I limit this bit of code to only operate with the one simple product I have, rather than all the products and variations, or other simple products I may add in the future ?

Would appreciate some guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First if you look to [`add_filter()` function documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/), you will see that the third argument is related to the hook priority (in your case 98)…

To target simple products only you will use the `WC_Product` `is_type()` method and you will define your desired product Ids in the code below:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'removing_product_tabs', 98 );
function removing_product_tabs( $tabs ) {
    // Get the global product object
    global $product;

    // HERE define your specific product Ids
    $targeted_ids = array( 37, 56, 63 );

    if( $product->is_type( 'simple' ) && in_array( $product->get_id(), $targeted_ids ) ) {
        unset( $tabs['description'] );            // Remove the description tab
        unset( $tabs['reviews'] );                // Remove the reviews tab
        unset( $tabs['additional_information'] ); // Remove the additional information tab      
    }

    return $tabs;
}
```

*Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (active active theme).* It should work.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. [I can't start a new line without this reply being posted ! ] Where do I get the targeted_ids from ?

Comment: @user913916 The $targeted_Ids is an array of your desired product IDs

Comment: Ok, I've given it a try and its nearly there. I think we have some custom tabs instead of whats provided in the code I've copied. Certainly it removed the text from the 'description' but left the box empty - might be because the other tabs were populated. None the less a good start - thanks so much. I'll do more on Monday morning.